# To get the maximum number of products giving a limit of money

Tags: python, algorithm

The question is giving a list of product price like [2,3,5,1,1,2,1] and a budget of 5, output should be the maximum number of product that can purchase. For this one is 4 ([1,1,2,1])

I have my code below, sometimes it works but for price like [2,3,5,1], budget = 7 and it should be 3 but it is 2. Can you guys help check which part of my code is wrong? Thank you

```
def getMaximumOutfits(money,outfits):
  result = []
  spent = 0
  max_length = 0
  for i in range(len(outfits)):
      spent+=outfits[i]
      if spent <=money:
          if i!=len(outfits)-1:
              result.append(outfits[i])
          else:
              result.append(outfits[i])
              if max_length < len(result):
                  max_length = len(result)
      else:
          if max_length<len(result):
              max_length = len(result)
          result=[]
          spent = outfits[i]
          if spent <= money:
              result.append(outfits[i])
  print(max_length)
```

Comment: You forgot to sort by price, I think.

Comment: You would better use itertools for such a problem

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
The initial debugging is your responsibility.

Comment: Once you sort by price you simply increment spent by outfits[i] while `spent <=money:`.  The number of items then is i+1, where i is the last i that last the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've set up your program to try every option is counter-intuitive. Instead of retrying from scratch every time, if you sort the list first you only need to go through the list once. You can do this quite simply by putting at the start `outfits=sorted(outfits)` .
This eliminates the need for most of your code, as the cheapest possible option will always be the first.

Another improvement you can make, is that you don't actually need to keep track of things like spent and result. Since the only thing you care about is how many items you can buy, you can just create a variable (that starts at 0) and add 1 to it every time you can afford another item.

Another possible improvement is that instead of checking every time `if spent<money` you can just treat money as yout 'balance', and subtract the amount of money you spent from the total, until money is less than 0.

Just as a quick side point, instead of writing

```
for i in len(outfits):
    spent+=outfits[i]
```

You can iterate through the list itself

```
for i in outfits:
    spent+=i
```

and get the same result

Your final code should look something like this:

```
def getMaximumOutfits(money,outfits):
    outfits=sorted(outfits)#sorts the list from smallest --> biggest
    items=0
    max_size=0
    for i in outfits: #goes through each element in the outfit list
        money-=i   #subtracts the cost of this item from the remaining money
        if money<0: #if they couldn't afford this item
            max_size=items #the amount of items they had before this one is their max
        else: #if they can afford this item
            items+=1 #the total items goes up by 1
    return(max_size)
print(getMaximumOutfits(7,[2,3,5,1]))
>>> 3
```

Any questions feel free to ask ;)

Comment: Really in details and helpful. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Sort your prices from smallest to largest before running your loop.  For your example it adds 2, then 3, then 5 and sees that is larger than 7 so it returns 2.  If it was in order it would add 1, 2, and 3 before getting to 5.